# Change Class Name of a div in Jquery after find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a brief quesiton about the nautre of jquery.

I tried to change the class name of an element using Jquery by using the argument below.

```
var classman=$('body').find('div')[2].className('anything')
```

body has several different divs and I picked the third one by
using .find('div')[2].

When I logged it, .find() argument spits out the whole html line 
and I checked the type of it and console says it's "object"
So I was expecting I could access tot he element by typing like

**classman.class**

but neither the first approach nor the second approach didn't worked out. What should I do to change the second element and the change the class?

Thank you in advance.
I'm not a heavy user of Jquery but Just curious about it and wanted to know how to do it as a basic knowledge.

Comment: `find('div')[2]` returns the element not the jquery object.... then [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is a property not a function. Try `$('body').find('div').eq(2).addClass('anything')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a class in jquery you can do this as follows:

```js
$('body').find('div').addClass('name')

console.log($('body').find('div').attr('class'))
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="test">
  </div>
</body>
```

To get the classes of an element we use attr ('class') in jquery.

In your example you said you wanted to take the second element, to do this use the method eq, (eq. (1))

Example:

$('body').find('div').eq(1) // Get second element

Comment: Really appreciate!